# ¿Como hacer para imprimir un List que tengo guardado en un archivo txt?

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo que va guardando los datos de una Lista, mi problema se encuentra en poder imprimir los datos guardados en el txt, en pantalla. Estoy haciendo esto:
`public void mostrarArticulos(List listaDeArticulos) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("articulos.dat");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    List<articulos> ar = (List<articulos>) ois.readObject();
    for (articulos articulos : ar)
        System.out.println(articulos);

    System.out.println("1-Volver al menu principal\n2-Salir");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

}`
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0D0A4E75. Busqué y dice que es por iniciar varios ObjectInputStream pero no entendi bien. Ojala alguien pueda ejemplificarme una forma de imprimir las cosas guardadas en el archivo txt.

el codigo con el cual escribo en el txt es el siguiente:

```
archi2.createFile(rutaArticulos);
                AgregarArticulos(listaDeArticulos);
                System.out.println("Guardar?\n1-Si\n2-No");
                Scanner asd = new Scanner(System.in);
                int asd1 = asd.nextInt();
                
                if (asd1==1) {
                    FileWriter fout= new FileWriter(rutaArticulos, true);
                    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fout);
                    
                     for(articulos articulos : listaDeArticulos) {
                      output.write("\r\n" +"Numero: " + articulos.getNumero()+ "\r\n" +"Nombre: " +articulos.getNombre() + "\r\n" + "Codigo: " + articulos.getCodigo()+ "\r\n"+"Precio: " + articulos.getPrecio() + "\r\n"+"Stock: " + articulos.getStock() + "\r\r\n");
                       }
                    
                    output.close();
                    fout.close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas escribiendo caracteres en el archivo y tratando de leer un objeto.

Cuando intentas leer un objeto la cabecera no coincide con una escritura de objetos ( ObjectOutputStream ).

Usa FileReader para leer el archivo o ObjectOutputStream para escribirlo.
Ejemplo para leer usando FileReader:

```
    FileReader  fre = null;
    BufferedReader bre = null;
    
    try{ 
        fre = new FileReader("nombre.txt");
        bre = new BufferedReader(fre);
        
        String s = null;
        
        while( (s = bre.readLine() ) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO lectura");
    }finally{ // cerrar bre y fre }
```

faltan hacer los close() para fre y bre.

Comment: Ahhh ya veo mi error, muchas gracias por ayudarme, funciono al primer intento!

Comment: puede ser posible que al guardarlo en el archivo, se me limpie el arraylist? Porque luego necesito modificar elementos dentro de el y me aparece vacio

Comment: Lo que estas guardando en el archivo es texto, cuando lo lees recuperas strings de texto no el objeto arrayList. Si lo que querés es guardar el objeto podes usar FileOutputSream para escribir. Mira esto [enlace](http://www.chuidiang.org/java/ficheros/ObjetosFichero.php)  ( la lectura no funciona ) . Podes: 1- guardar el objeto ArrayList, 2- Recuperar el objeto Arraylist 3- Modificar los que necesites, 4- volver a guardar el objeto arraylist.  No puedo incluir un ejemplo con código desde aquí.

Comment: gracias lucas, es justamente lo que necesito, ojala pueda hacerlo. Te voy avisando

Comment: hola damian, mira esto tal vez te ayude [enlace](https://gist.github.com/lucasDRR/5e501677a6930b4df33b4fcac7f81048) . Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Lucas!

Comment: ahi en el enlace te dejé una consulta porque me lee un solo objeto y por lo tanto muestra un solo objeto de los archivos :)